# Automatic border colour colour code

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

What's the color code (ENUM) of the automatic border colour which is 25% grey?
Or at least it's RGB value.

I've been searching for half an hour and couldn't find it anywhere. Here's the image of the border colour I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: do you mean gridlines? those cells don't have any border and the displayed color of the gridlines can differ by OS, Excel version or user settings...

Comment: I thought they had a colour well thanks, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those cells don't have any border and you can [Show or hide gridlines on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-gridlines-on-a-worksheet-aad94875-e9f7-4174-8e0a-b26f4adc3fb4) in the Excel settings.

Answer (score 1):

To change the colour of the gridlines, go into Excel Options, Advanced (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>) and scroll down to **Display options for this worksheet**. You can toggle gridline display and select a non-standard gridline colour there.

Alternately, you can run this on the [Application.ActiveWindow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835855.aspx).

```
    ActiveWindow.GridlineColorIndex = 15   '25% grey
```

See [Window.GridlineColorIndex property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208585%28v=office.12%29.aspx).